# Swift 3 - Tableview shows behind tab and nav bars despite attempts otherwise

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am using Swift 3 and developing for iPhone 7.

When the user clicks a button, I instantiate a `TableViewController` as so:

```
// Instantiate the Table View Controller that the info will be on
let detailVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dvc") as! ResultsVC

detailVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

and have the parent view controller be able to present it.

However, the problem is that it's appearing behind the tab and nav bars.

[image]

Despite trying to set these things in the `ResultsVC`'s `viewDidLoad` method:

```
// 49 is the height for tab bar, 64 is the height for nav bar
let adjustForTabbarInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(49, 0, 64, 0);        
self.tableView.contentInset = adjustForTabbarInsets;
self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = adjustForTabbarInsets;
```

OR

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

I've even gone into Xcode, clicked on the view controller in question in the Storyboard and unchecked:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code in which you present the new view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can try set constraints. As iOS9 and iOS10 uses 49 points for the Tab Bar and 64 points for a navigation bar, so we can set constraints with constants:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 64).isActive = true
    collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -49).isActive = true
    collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: Hm, that doesn't seem to work for me...yet.  I used your code and now it doesn't seem that the view is behind the tab and nav bars anymore but instead the view is completely black.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually bringing the view to the front

```
parentView.bringSubview(toFront: coveredView)
```